# Get line break offset in a Spannable object

Tags: android, spannablestring

I have a `Spannable` object formatted like so:

> This is the first line.
>
> This is the second line. It's more fun than the first.
>
> Why not, lets add a third line.

When I throw it in a `TextView`, it shows the line breaks as expected. What I want to know is, how do I get the index of the line breaks from the `Spannable` object? I looked at all the Spans applied and all I saw were `RelativeSizeSpan`s and `StyleSpan`s. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was treating a `Spannable` as if it was it's own special class, but it extends `CharSequence`, which means the underlying data is just normal text. I just did an `indexOf(' ')` and was able to find my solution.